# Mertens conjecture - bounds

Tags: number-theory, conjectures

The disproven Mertens Conjecture states that $$|M(n)|\leq \sqrt{n}$$
If it is bounded at all, would the bounds
$$|M(n)|\leq \sqrt{2n\log(\log (n))}$$
not be more realistic, and still consistent with the counterexamples suggested by Odlyzko and te Riele, owing to the [law of the iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that $\mid M(x)\mid\le x$ since the absolute value of the Moebius function is bounded by $1$. So it *is* indeed bounded.
However, already a bound of the form, say, $O(x^{0.9})$ is not proven so far. This would of course follow from the Riemann Hypothesis. RH would imply  a bound of the form $O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$. For good unconditional bounds see the paper of [Nathan Ng](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~nathanng/RESEARCH/mobius2b.pdf). Furthermore,
a discussion with more information can be found here: [Is $M(x)=O(x^σ)$ possible with $σ≤1$ even if the Riemann hypothesis is false?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170073/is-mx-ox-possible-with-1-even-if-the-riemann-hypothesis-is-false).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - I will also follow your links provided.